# Prerequisites of Vector Calculus for Freshman

Tags: calculus, education, vectors, book-recommendation

I'm doing BSc as Physics major, i had studied Calculus and Vectors in 12th grade. For now i want to study Mathematical physics myself, i had decided to follow Arfken but it starts from the topics which are too far in the syllabus. 
I need a best sequence of studying vector calculus, and please tell me prerequisites for better understanding. 
Thx.

Comment: Maybe you should post this to mathematics educators site instead

Comment: Okay sorry if i have gone against the rules!

Comment: I don't think it is against the rules but there it is more likely you will get answers.

Comment: Okay, thanks for suggestion :)